# Nexus 7 Wi-Fi (4.4.2)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm stuck on step 4:
To bootstrap on the devel channel or reinstall afresh (wiping everything) the recommended command is to be run from the bootloader:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel devel --bootstrap
```

When I use that command, it says command does not exist

When I use instructions for manual install:

I use the first command, `adb reboot fastboot` - it works and it reboots. But when I move to the next command:

```
fastboot flash recovery trusty-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
```

all that happens is I get this: 
"waiting for device" and it hangs there forever.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo adb devices`?

Comment: 015d3248b7540e07    device

Comment: Is the device screen blank? *You may need to disable MIR (X-windows replacement).*

Comment: The device screen is Android's "home screen". Nothing is happening when the commands are entered.